# Jquery unable to assign onclick on button array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to adapt the commented out code at the bottom that works for a single button to work for more than one buttons.

So I changed the 'menu-toggle' being from an id to a class. And in the html I added class='menu-toggle' to the buttons.

I am getting an array of the elements using a jquery selector. Then looping on them, and assigning the onclick event.

```
// Toggles the sidebar
const buttons = $('.menu-toggle');

buttons.forEach(
    function (element){
        element.onclick(
            function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
            }
        )
    }
)

/*
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
*/
```

Edit: I accepted Alireza's answer, as he fixed my code. But I actually used Zoli's answer, as it is more concise. Aside from the bug in the code, the actual problem was that the browser was caching the *.js file this code is in. So my changes were not reloading. I cleared the cache from privacy settings, and now it works.

Comment: every button will do the same thing ... `$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");` is that the problem? that each button does exactly the same thing as that's what your code does? You haven't described what the issue is

Comment: `buttons` is a jQuery object, not an array. Does jQuery even have a forEach method? It would help if you used the live demo feature of the question editor to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Bravo There is a button that toggles the sidebar. But on very small screens, when the sidebar is shown, that button is occluded by sidebar. So I want to add an additional button to the sidebar itself. So yes, I want two buttons with the exact behavior.

Comment: ok, and the browser developer tools console has no errors?

Comment: You could just use CSS for that matter @Zargo

Comment: @Bravo I see no errors in the console.

Comment: @Zargo - that's really odd, because jquery results **dont** have a `forEach` method, you **should** be getting an error - perhaps you're not looking in the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `forEach` functions exist on array, so you need to use spared operator (`...`) to convert buttons to array to make sure you can use `forEach` function. (Probably you get the error `buttons.forEach is not a function` now)

```js
const buttons = $('.menu-toggle');
        [...buttons].forEach(
            function (element) {
                element.onclick =
                    function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
                    }
            }
        )
```

```css
.toggled {
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <button class="menu-toggle">button1</button>
    <button class="menu-toggle">button2</button>
    <button class="menu-toggle">button3</button>
    <button class="menu-toggle">button4</button>

    <p id="wrapper">this is p</p>
```

Comment: @Zargo If you check the console probably see the error `buttons.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Your answer does not work either. I don't see why though. I don't see an error in the console.

Comment: @Zargo I put working snippet for you. you can see the `toggled` class add and removed on each click!

Comment: I am sure you must get an error `buttons.forEach is not a function` if you don't get error maybe this line of your code does not called. Can you show me the more details of your code?

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as changing the ID selector to a class selector.

```
$(".menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

jQuery will attach the event handler to all selected elements, whether that's a single element (in the case of an ID selector) or multiple elements (found by a class selector or other...).

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it does not work.

Comment: this should work; you might want to check and wrap it inside $(document).ready(function(){...}) if it doesnt for u

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", ".menu-toggle", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```